# Factoring Finite Morphisms through Open Immersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a somewhat silly question, but I was wondering the following. Assume X, Y, and Z are schemes and consider the composition
$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Z $ and assume $g\circ f $ is a finite morphism. Say for simplicity Z is affine and that $f$ is an open immersion of an affine open subscheme of Y. Assume further the example where Y and Z are irreducible varieties, then the question is whether X being finite over Z forces X to be equal to Y in order to have a well defined morphism from Y to Z.  Is it true that in most cases $f$ is necessarily an isomorphism? It seems intuitively true in the case of irreducible varieties from the fact that $g\circ f$ is proper.

Perhaps it comes from the fact that quasi-finiteness + properness $\implies$ finiteness and tracking down where you get affineness of the morphism in the argument from these two hypotheses? More precisely, how you get from the inverse image of an affine open being covered by affines along with the other assumptions of quasi-finiteness to the inverse image actually being an affine open as per the finiteness definition?

Comment: Since $g\circ f$ is finite it is proper, and then (assuming some separatedness) the morphism $f$ is proper. Thus it is a proper open immersion and thus an open and closed immersion. Since $Y$ is connected, the image of $f$ equals $Y$.